# I need help making a random number generator as a lock in a simple game

Tags: python, random, generator

Basically, I wanted to be able to make a code that would generate a random number and have the user try and guess that number by putting in an input. I thought it would work, but it just runs the else statement everytime even if I do guess the right number.

```
import random
def main():
  values = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 10]
  a = random.choice(values)
  print (a) ##########To see what the number is#########
  b = input('Enter a number: ')
  if b == a:
    print('You have guessed the number!')
  else:
    print('Try again')
    main()
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition is checking a string with an integer. Convert the input number `b` to int using `int(b)` before checking or while checking.

```
import random
def main():
    values = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 10]
    a = random.choice(values)
    print (a) ##########To see what the number is#########
    b = input('Enter a number: ')
    if int(b) == a:
        print('You have guessed the number!')
    else:
        print('Try again')
        main()
main()
```

To know more, you can print the type of `a` and `b` inside the function

```
print(type(a))
print(type(b))

<class 'int'>
<class 'str'>
```

Updated the indentation of `main()` to be inside else condition, as per suggestions from @nfnneil.

Comment: The `main()` line isn't indented properly, just a friendly heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Python 3, the problem is that you're comparing a string to a number, so it's always false.  Just change:

```
b = input('Enter a number: ')
```

To:

```
b = int(input('Enter a number: '))
```

Then `b` will be a number (as long as the user enters a number).

Answer (score 0):

A couple things.  One, you don't convert the result of `input` to `int`.  So, `'7'` will never equal `7` because of how programming works, unless you convert it using the `int()` function.   Second thing, I noticed that you are using recursion to solve this problem.  Unfortunately, in your implementation you seem to be redefining the number to guess.  I can't imagine this is your intent for a "lock guessing game".  So, I rewrote it without this pitfall:

## If you don't need recursion:

```
import random

values = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 10]
number = random.choice(values)
print("The secret number is {}".format(number))
while True:
    guess = int(input('Enter a number: '))
    if guess == number:
        print('You have guessed the number!')
        break
    else:
        print('Try again')
```

## If you must use recursion:

```
import random
def main(a=None):
    if a == None:
        values = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 10]
        a = random.choice(values)
        print (a) ##########To see what the number is#########
    b = int(input('Enter a number: '))
    if b == a:
        print('You have guessed the number!')
    else:
        print('Try again')
        main(a)
main()
```